# Unable to find replacement for `DisposeListener` class

Tags: java, jxbrowser

Upgrading to 7.21.2 from 6.20.  Having trouble finding a callback that replaces the `com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.DisposeListener` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `BrowserClosed` event to track when a particular browser is closed:

```
browser.on(BrowserClosed.class, event -> { System.out.println("Bye") });
```

And `EngineClosed` to detect when the whole engine has been closed:

```
engine.on(EngineClosed.class, event -> {});
```